# Intellij to ask which project when opening

Tags: intellij-idea

In `Eclipse` they have the option to be able to specify a workspace or ask for a workspace when loading, Is there something similar for `Intellij`? So that I don't have to wait for it to finishing loading then reopen a different project and wait for that process to finish.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uncheck **File > Settings > System Settings > Reopen last project on startup**

Comment: For Intellij 14 I found system settings under Appearance & Behavior.